# jquery mtree onload open last clicked node with cookie option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, treeview

I am using mtree( sample you can see[here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Vertical-Accordion-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3-mtree-js/) for display my menu list nodes When i click on the node text (hyperlink) . I want to open the node which i clicked and all other nodes should be closed. I am using the following code.

In main.html page i have list with Africa,America,Asia,Europe,Oceania,Arctica and
Antarctica

Africa is having sub menu as: Algeria,Marocco,Libya,Somalia,Kenya,Mauritania and South Africa( all are hyperlink text)
when I click on kenya text hyperlink it will redirects to kenya.html page so on load of kenya.html i want Africa menu list should open with Kenya text highlighted

main.html

```html
<body>
</div>
  <ul class="mtree transit">
    <li id ="shiva" class ="shiva"><a href="">Africa</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Algeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marocco</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Libya</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Somalia</a></li>
        <li><a href="kenya.html">Kenya</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mauritania</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">America</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">North-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">USA</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">California</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">San Diego</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sacramento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">San Francisco</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bakersville</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lousiana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Texas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nevada</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Virginia</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Middle-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Honduras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Guatemala</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">South-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Asia</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vietnam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mongolia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">North</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sweden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">East</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Romania</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bulgaria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">South</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greece</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">West</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">England</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Oceania</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Arctica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Antarctica</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src='jquery.velocity.min.js'></script> 
<script src="mtree.js"></script> 
<script src="shiva.js"></script> 
THIS IS MAIN PAGE
</body>
```

kenya.html

```html
<body onload="clickButton()">
</div>
  <ul class="mtree transit">
    <li id ="shiva" class ="shiva"><a href="" class="shiva">Africa</a>
      <ul id = "shiva">
        <li><a href="#">Algeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marocco</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Libya</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Somalia</a></li>
        <li><a href="kenya.html">Kenya</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mauritania</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">America</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">North-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">USA</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">California</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">San Diego</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sacramento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">San Francisco</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bakersville</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lousiana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Texas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nevada</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Virginia</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Middle-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Honduras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Guatemala</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">South-America</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uruguay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Asia</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vietnam</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mongolia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Europe</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">North</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sweden</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Finland</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">East</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Romania</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bulgaria</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">South</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Greece</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">West</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">England</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portugal</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Oceania</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Arctica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Antarctica</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src='jquery.velocity.min.js'></script> 
<script src="mtree.js"></script> 
<script src="shiva.js"></script> 
THIS IS Kenya PAGE
</body>
```

Comment: You solve that problem?